Solving $\int\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\dots}}}\ dx$
I have attempted below, but I would appreciate any corrections or even a different, more efficient way to solve it.
$$I = \int\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\dots}}}\ dx$$
consider: $y=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\dots}}} \quad$ meaning $y=\sqrt{x+y} $.
Squaring on both sides: $$y^2=x+y$$ $$y^2-y-x=0$$ $$y=\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$$
I continued by substituting $y$ into our original integral:
$$I=\int y \ dx = \int\left[ \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}\right] dx$$
$$I=\frac{x}{2} \pm \frac{1}{2}\int\sqrt{1+4x}\ dx$$
$$\text{let } u=1+4x$$ $$du=4 \ dx \Rightarrow dx=\frac{du}{4}$$
$$I=\frac{x}{2} \pm \frac{1}{2}\int\sqrt{u}\ \frac{du}{4}$$
$$I=\frac{x}{2} \pm \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{2}{3}\cdot u^{\frac{3}{2}}\cdot \frac{du}{4}$$ $$I=\frac{x}{2} \pm \frac{1}{12}u^{\frac{3}{2}}+c$$
$$(\text{let }u=1+4x)$$
$$I=\frac{x}{2} \pm \frac{1}{12}(1+4x)^{\frac{3}{2}}+c$$

$y=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\ldots}}$ must be positive, therefore only valid solution is $I=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{12}(1+4x)^{\frac{3}{2}}+c$

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
